# fuse return No such file or directory error after mount

Tags: hadoop, fuse, cloudera-cdh

I am running CDH5. As root, I am trying to mount the following mount point.

```
[root@localhost ]#  ll -d /export
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 21 08:53 /export
```

After mount, I got the following error.

```
[root@localhost ]# hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://localhost:8020 /export
INFO /data/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.1/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/fuse-dfs/fuse_options.c:164 Adding FUSE arg /export
[root@localhost ]# ls -l /export
ls: cannot access /export: Input/output error
[root@localhost ]# hdfs dfs -ls /export
ls: `/export': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hostname instead of localhost. I faced the same issue, after changing localhost to hostname which is also defined in hosts file, it got fixed.

```
hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://{hostname}:8020 /export
```

According to [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_hdfs_mountable.html)

> In an HA deployment, use the HDFS nameservice instead of the NameNode URI; that is, use the value of dfs.nameservices in hdfs-site.xml.